# CheckBoxList ListItem Count always 0 after adding data dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, comboboxlist

I have the following code in `aspx` code. I wanted to add `ListItem` check boxes to  `ColumnsList` and Find all the checked one's on button click.

But when I try to get the selected items on button click the ColumnsList  count becomes 0.

```
<asp:checkboxlist runat="server" EnableViewState="true" id="ColumnsList"/>
```

In code behind I add data to my ColumnsList as follows

```
public override void OnLoad()
{
    if(!this.IsPostBack)
    {
       this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text1",  Value = "value1"    });
       this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text2",  Value = "value2"  });
    }
}
```

// Here is the button click listener

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // Count is 0 instead of 2
    var count = this.ColumnsList.Items.Count;
    foreach(ListItem item in this.ColumnsList.Items)
    {
        var selected = item.Selected;
        // add selected to a list..etc

    }
}
```

Note: The application is Deployed in share point 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up moving the code which loads the List from pageload to OnInit as follows and it worked.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
  this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text1",  Value = "value1"    });
  this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text2",  Value = "value2"  });
```

}

Answer (score 6):

I tried to simulate what you were trying and here is the solution step by step.

> Step 1: Instead of creating `override OnLoad()` method, you can use
>   `Page_Load()` method to add items to your `ComboBoxList` control, like
>   below. **Don't** **forget** to put a `comma` between `Text` and `Value` property while creating a new `ListItem`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text1",  Value = "value1" });
        this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Text2", Value = "value2" }); 
        this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Text3", Value = "value3" });
        this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Text4", Value = "value4" });
    }
}
```

> Step 2: After this, I created a button click event like yours, but
>   wrote only single line there to get the count of selected items as
>   shown below.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var count = this.ColumnsList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Count(li => li.Selected);
}
```

**Note**: Check your button click event. `this.ColumnsList.Items.Count` will return you count of the items that were there in the ComboBoxList and `item.Selected` from loop will tell you whether the item was selected or not. However `var selected` will give you the status of last item, as you are overriding its value for each item.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. Your solution did not work. One thing I have not mentioned in my post is that I am working on MVC application deployed in share-point. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Amete The code that you mentioned, is not suitable for MVC. I'm surprised, how would that work.

Comment: @Amete I'm also surprised to see a web form architecture in a MVC. Definitely you are messing with two different architectures. MVC doesn't support web form architecture and events like **OnLoad, Page_Load and PreInit** etc.

Comment: True, if you're in MVC, your .cshtml's will parse for ActionResults(get-post), while as web forms(ASPX) will parse anything that's inside a <form></form> with runat="server" in them.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion it is web forms(ASPX)  deployed in sharepoint.

Answer (score 2):

You should add dynamic data on [PreInit](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_life_cycle.htm) evet when you need to reate or re-create dynamic controls:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.IsPostBack)
    {
       this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text1", Value = "value1" });
       this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text2", Value = "value2" });
    }
}
```

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) about page life cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine in my solution except for the following:

The implementation of your OnLoad does not have the override parameter EventArgs. In my solution, its a requirement to declare the EventArgs parameter in OnLoad().

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   //base.OnLoad(e);
   if(!this.IsPostBack)
   {
       this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text1", Value = "value1"    });
       this.ColumnsList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text= "Text2", Value = "value2"  });
   }
}
```

And lastly, is the comma separator in `Text='text' Value='value'` to `Text='text', Value='value'`
Anything else works fine.

EDIT : here's my button implementation.

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem itemList in ColumnsList.Items)
    {
       if (itemList.Selected)
       {
          // selected
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just perfect. @Amete I am also wondering though you have written Private method for button click it is hitting debug poing?

Comment: oh, then please move your comments their post, its confusing. :)

Comment: sorry for confusion. Removed comments :)